# Storyboard prototype cell attributed text label does not display same as prototype

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

When using a TableView with Custom Cells, I have 4 labels of different fonts/colors.  In Storyboard (Left side of picture), they show up as different fonts/sizes and colors, but when I run the app in Simulator (Right side of picture), they revert back to standard fonts and sizes.
 (Needed 10 rep points to post screenshot)

I set the label to "Attributed, Picked the font, color, and size in storyboard (Under label) and all looks good in the prototype cell on the storyboard.  But when I run the app, these attributes are being ignored.   What am I missing?

Comment: Lets see your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Show your code and link to the screenshot

Comment: @wain I cant link screenshot as I don't have enough stackoverflow rep points yet.

Comment: @TimothyMoose `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @cardTransCell";  SCECardTransactionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  cell.lblAmount.text=@"12,345.67";  return cell;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the label's text in code, the storyboard attributes are overwritten. One way to solve this is to copy the attributes from the label and and then reapply them when setting the text:

```
UILabel *label = cell.lblAmount;
NSMutableDictionary *existingAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[label.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:nil]];
label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"12,345.67" attributes:existingAttributes];
```

Note that you don't need to do this with the built in labels, e.g. `textLabel`. I think the table view is somehow re-applying the storyboard attributes before displaying the cell.

Comment: this kind of starts to work.  I'm getting the attributedText from the storyboard now, but your 3rd line is not changing my text to "@"MyText".   it is the original sample text I put in the Storyboard.

Comment: Your `label` variable is probably `nil`. You need to replace the first line with whatever method you use to access your custom label.

Comment: I updated my sample code per the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you posted above.

Comment: I actually found I didn't need "AttributedText" at all, I was able to choose "Custom" under fonts, then use the font and color I wanted with "Plain" attributes.  It is good to know how to use "AttributedText" now as well for changing the look of words within the sentence.